# My Tezbox can't connect to https://mainnet.tezrpc.me

Tags: rpc, tezbox

I am trying to make a XTZ delegation. Downloaded the Tezbox, but shows 
"
Error
Level N/A
Not Connected
https://mainnet.tezrpc.me
"
what's wrong for my tezbox. And how to fix this?

Comment: Tezbox is no longer a supported wallet. Please migrate to galleon, ledger live or kukai among others. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Tezbox is no longer a supported wallet. Please migrate to galleon, ledger live or kukai among others.

A tutorial on how to migrate from tezbox to galleon is available on the official site

https://cryptonomic.tech/galleon.html